# How can I drop rows which aren't in a given time period?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure that this question is not really helpful and could mean a lot of thinks so I'll try to explain the question with an example.

So my goal is to delete rows in a DataFrame like the following one if the row can't be part in a line of consecutive days which are as big as a given time period t. If t for example is 3, then the last row needs to be deleted, because there is a gap between the last and the row before. If t would be 4 then also the first three rows must be deleted, hence the 07.04.2012 or 03.04.2012 is missing. Hopefully you can understand what I try to explain here.

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 04.04.2012 | 24 |
| 05.04.2012 | 21 |
| 06.04.2012 | 20 |
| 08.04.2012 | 21 |
| 09.04.2012 | 23 |
| 10.04.2012 | 21 |
| 11.04.2012 | 26 |
| 13.04.2012 | 24 |

My attempt was to iterate over the values in the column 'Date' and check for every element x in the column if the value of the element x subtracted by the value of element x + t = -t. If this is not the case the whole row of the element should be deleted. But while I was searching how you can iterate over a DataFrame I read several times that it is not recommended to do that, because this needs a lot of computing time for big DataFrames. Unfortunately I couldn't find any other method or function which could do this. Therefore, I would be really glad if someone could help me out here. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't understand. What is this - the presence of staff at work? Anyway, you can use many features in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases.  If you want speed then the first issue is : input data format: excel file ...

Answer (score 0):

With the dates as index you can expand the index of the dataframe to include the missing days. The new dates will create `nan` values. Create groups for every `nan` value with [`.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)[`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and count the size of each groups. Finally select the rows with a count larger or equal to the desired time period.

```
period = 3

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df[df.groupby(df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()))
                .Value.isna().cumsum())
                .transform('count').ge(period).Value].reset_index()
```

Output

```
        Date  Value
0 2012-04-04     24
1 2012-04-05     21
2 2012-04-06     20
3 2012-04-08     21
4 2012-04-09     23
5 2012-04-10     21
6 2012-04-11     26
```

---

To create the dataframe used in this solution

```
t = '''
Date    Value
04.04.2012  24
05.04.2012  21
06.04.2012  20
08.04.2012  21
09.04.2012  23
10.04.2012  21
11.04.2012  26
13.04.2012  24
'''
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', parse_dates=['Date'],
            date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```